# Powerpivot - Create flag if the row value of one column exists anywhere in another column

Tags: excel, powerpivot

What I'm trying to accomplish doesn't seem too tricky, and should be doable I just can't seem to crack it.

All I need to do is create a calculated column that flags whether or not the row value in one column exists anywhere in another column within the same table.

```
  id | Code 1        | Code 2         | Attempted results
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | 1095829       | 1093895        | Y               
   2 | 1093895       | 1838949        | N               
   3 | 1095289       | 1093910        | Y               
   4 | 1093910       | 1840193        | N
```

So essentially, is Code 1 found anywhere in the code 2 column

Comment: Hi, this question does not appear to be about programming. It fits better the [su] site.

Comment: given that it actually involves a "calculated" field, I would say it does fall into SO's definition of a programming question. That said, posting on SuperUser is also a valid option :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using an IF/MATCH formula. For example:

```
=IF(MATCH(B2,C:C,0),"Duplicate", "Unique")
```

This would check if B2 (1095829) shows up anywhere in the C column. If it does, it returns "Duplicate" to that cell, if it does not, then it returns "Unique".